# Which MySQL Query style should be used to make deductions or additions to database values?

Tags: mysql

When using MySQL Query to make deductions from stored values, is there a best approach?

Which of these two approaches is better? (I'm Working with PHP)

```
$amount=500;
$newBalance=$oldBalance-$amount;
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET wallet = '".$newBalance."' WHERE userId=5";
```

Or this

```
$amount=500;
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET wallet = wallet-$amount WHERE userId=5";
```

I noticed that most codes use the 1st approach.
However, I am concerned that the value of the **wallet** may change when several instances of a user access my API at a time.

My users have websites and these websites (connected to my API) Could be used by many users at a time hence the possibility of creating more than one instance of a particular user per time.

I thought the second approach was safer but I have noticed that the first approach seems to be more commonly used.

Comment: The second method is generally preferred. If you use the first method, use a transaction to solve the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Note that in both cases you should be using a prepared statement rather than substituting variables directly into the SQL string.

Comment: The first method is common because there are lots of poor programmers out there.

Comment: `$oldBalance-$amount` That seems like a bad idea for a few reasons. In a multithreaded environment the final balance could be wrong if multiple requests were updating at the same time, i.e. race conditions. Also, if `$oldBalance` were a form variable, a malicious user could modify the balance at will. For those reasons, and the ones above, I'd vote for a modified version of option 2 that used prepared statements and proper transactions.